# getSignedPlayerInfoAsync() for Facebook Instant Games, does it need to be called every request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

The documentation mentions using `FBInstant.player.getSignedPlayerInfoAsync()` to get a signature when communicating with a custom backend.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/guides/bots-and-server-communication

Can I store the signature in a variable at the start of the app and then just use it throughout all the XMLHttpRequests for the current session?

Or do I need to call it everytime I make an XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Once you look at what parameter that method gets passed, that question should kinda answer itself, no?

Answer (score 1):

You are free to only call it once, however this will not allow you to validate the `issued_at` time, or to encrypt custom payloads.